# How to access secure kerberized hadoop using just java API

Tags: java, security, hadoop, kerberos, jaas

I am pretty new to Kerberos. I am using a shared Hadoop cluster. My admin has provided me with a username and a password and the location of the KDC server.

Is it possible to use just the JAVA GSS API and the Hadoop USerGroupInformation class to access the Hadoop cluster.

For a non-kerberos hadoop cluster, this would be the code snippet I would use to, say read a file from HDFS :

```
String uname = <Some username>;
UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser(uname);
ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>(){

   public Void run() throws Exception {

      HdfsConfiguration hdfsConf = new HdfsConfiguration();
      ... SETUP Configuration ...
      FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(hdfsConf);
      ... Use 'fs' to read/write etc ...
   }

});
```

Now for a secure cluster, I am also provided the kerberos password for the user..
Could someone please provide me with what are the exact changes I need to make to the above code snippet to first access the KDC and do a kinit and then proceed with the HDFS operation

Please remember, in the environment I am planning to deploy the Java app, I might not have 'kinit' installed locally, so invoking the kinit process from within java is not an option.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: if you can't kinit before executing the java program from your client, then you cannot deploy your job against the secure cluster, unless you build a kerberos client into your program.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `keytab` file for the identity of the `UserGroupInformation` superuser, you can use the `org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil#login(…)` API offered in the `hadoop-common` library, to log in directly from your code. The full API can be found [**here**](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable1/api/org/apache/hadoop/security/SecurityUtil.html#login(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

This will need to be done *before* you create the remote user (or more generally, before any socket connection of any form can be made to the various service daemons), as the invocation would otherwise fail with no login credentials being found.

You do not need `krb5-workstation` packages and utilities installed or available on the execution machine for this to work.

Comment: I'm curious about this, will it work if my server is outside the kerberos cluster? meaning that the server that launches the API is not kerberised, will it work by just specifying the provided keytab?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I'll just put what I could not find easily in docs.

`Ensure your site XML files are in your classpath.`